# update column to two based on condition

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to modify ONE column, I want to set some rows as `true` the others convert them to false

```
update products set on_sale=False where status=1 and seller=test;
update products set on_sale=true Where price > 100 and status=1 and seller=test;
```

the above works, but I believe it can be done in 1 query, I.e something like this

```
\\ python syntax for the if condition
update prodcuts set on_sale=(True if price > 100 else False) WHERE status=1 and seller=test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a single update with the help of a `CASE` expression:

```sql
UPDATE products
SET on_sale = CASE WHEN price > 100 THEN True ELSE False END
WHERE status = 1 AND seller = test;
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted